# Visual Studio 2017 Azure Function Template does not have files like - run.csx or project.json

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2017, azure-functions

I am using Visual Studio 2017 preview(2) to create Azure Function. The template generated for it is very different from what I get in Visual Studio 2015.

The Visual Studio 2017 template create a .cs file for function, and template structure looks like below :

[image: Visual Studio 2017 Azure Function Template Structure]

All functions are created as individual .cs file and there are no run.csx, project.json or function.json files, due to which I am not able to specify function specific dependencies and settings

If we see the earlier template (see the image below) with Visual Studio 2015, it well represent the folders and files available on Azure Portal. It has functions in individual folder with all .json and .csx file. This folder structure helps in segregating files related to a particular function (which is not the case with VS 2017 template)

[image: Visual Studio 2015 Azure Function Template Structure]

In VS 2017, I want to specify function specific dependencies and binding settings by adding project.json and function.json. Please let me know about the  way to achieve this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is intended. Azure Functions team changed the way you develop and deploy Function Apps in Visual Studio 2017. Now, it's basically a compiled class library, with functions being  static methods with proper attributes.

You should not be editing `function.json` manually anymore; instead use WebJob SDK attributes. Packages management is done the normal .NET way via NuGet packages.

The "old way" still works from within Azure portal for quick prototyping and experiments, but Visual Studio won't support it anymore.

Comment: Thanks , this answers to a lot of my questions , but one thing is still bothering me that,  with no project.json file , is it good to share the dependencies across all functions in a function app.
This may not be a bad idea at all if we consider a function app to be a group of related functions, but wondering what should be the best practice.

Comment: @RamkumarSingh Indeed, you should keep your app relatively small and cohesive. Effectively Function App is on par with other .NET application types.

Comment: Just a small clarification... `function.json` hasn't been deprecated, and in cases where necessary, it may still be used even in VS if needed. You'd just be responsible for the entry point, file and binding configuration in that case.

Comment: The Link is dead.